# compare ratings involving integers and NA

Tags: r

I have ratings by different raters:

```
df <- structure(list(SZ = c(1, 1, NA, 0, NA, 1, 1), 
                     SZ_ptak = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to compare them to find ratings that differ. This code works fine as long as both raters assigned either `1` or `0`. If one rating is `NA` and the other is `1` or `0`, I also want to obtain the value `1` in column `diff_SZ` - how can that be done?

```
df %>%
  mutate(diff_SZ = +(SZ != SZ_ptak))
  SZ SZ_ptak diff_SZ
1  1       1       0
2  1       1       0
3 NA      NA      NA
4  0      NA      NA
5 NA      NA      NA
6  1       1       0
7  1       0       1
```

Desired:

```
  SZ SZ_ptak diff_SZ
1  1       1       0
2  1       1       0
3 NA      NA      NA
4  0      NA       1   <--
5 NA      NA      NA
6  1       1       0
7  1       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be easy to understand if you list out the conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(diff_SZ = case_when(is.na(SZ) & is.na(SZ_ptak) ~ NA_real_, 
                             is.na(SZ) | is.na(SZ_ptak) ~ 1, 
                             SZ != SZ_ptak ~ 1, 
                             TRUE ~ 0))

#  SZ SZ_ptak diff_SZ
#1  1       1       0
#2  1       1       0
#3 NA      NA      NA
#4  0      NA       1
#5 NA      NA      NA
#6  1       1       0
#7  1       0       1
```